# Create a new Excel sheet and name it

Tags: c#, excel

I only wrote my data to 1 Excel sheet, but I want to make a new sheet and call it "xxx" and write data in it.

Here is what I have now:

```
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass appExcel;
private static Workbook newWorkbook_First = null;
private static _Worksheet objsheet = null;

excel_init("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\excel2.xlsx");

for (int i = 1; i < WindowsXPLijst.Count; i++)
{
    excel_setValue("B" + i, WindowsXPLijst[i]);
}

excel_close();

static void excel_init(String path)
{
    appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        // then go and load this into excel
        newWorkbook_First = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(path, true, true);
        objsheet = (_Worksheet)appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
            appExcel.Visible = true;
            newWorkbook_First = appExcel.Workbooks.Add(1);
            objsheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)newWorkbook_First.Sheets[1];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("Error");
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

}

static void excel_setValue(string cellname, string value)
{
    objsheet.get_Range(cellname).set_Value(Type.Missing, value);
    objsheet.get_Range(cellname).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
}
```

I don't have that much changed yet, because I have no idea how to change this function:

```
static void excel_setValue(string cellname, string value, string tab)
{
     objsheet = tab // No ica what to exactly put here
}

{
    excel_setValue("B" + i, WindowsXPLijst[i], "xxx");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a new sheet after your last sheet:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet 
Set WS =Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.count)) 
WS.name = "xxx"
```

This code is a condensed version of the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840628/creating-and-naming-worksheet-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Stupid Question: It cannot find the type or namespace Dim. How to fix this?

Comment: This answer is written in VBA, whereas you're looking for a C# answer. It would probably make sense to remove the [tag:vba] tag from the question, @wouter

Comment: Oops... Youre right, it suggested the VBA tag, so I added it.. haha.. not so smart. Thanks for deleting the tag. I am very sorry @Paradox

Comment: Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;
newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();

Comment: the type or namespace name 'globals' could not be found @Paradox Could you help me with this?

Comment: Using my code it was just: `appExcel.Worksheets.Add();` Thanks for helping me out :)