# Create new sheet from button cell that pulls data into new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

When you click a green cell, a new sheet with new sheet name matching the green cell's name. The green cells are parents and the 'x' represents a child.  So In the newly created sheet there will be two columns. One for the Parent which will contain the parents Id and the second column which will display the child Id.(image below to demonstrate).  What is the best way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not show an attempt, I will just give you the bare bones required to get you started on your problem. This needs to be pasted on the sheet where your data will originate from
`(VBE > Sheet X > Paste code here)`

Every time you **double click** on a cell (`Target`), a new sheet will be created. Having this fire on a single click or selection change is too unpredictable.
The sheet name will = the value in the `Target` cell
The sheet will always be the furthest right sheet on your tab selection

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = Target.Value

End Sub
```

---

Things you may want to account for while completing your project:

1. Limit the target range to the cells where you want this to work. To implement this, research the `Intersect` method (or see #5 instead)
2. If your cell value that is double clicked has a value that is not compliant with sheet name limitations, this will error out. Research `Error Handling` to account for this (Or make sure every cell that you want this to apply to has a value that fits sheet name rules)
3. If you double click on the same cell twice, you will get an error (cannot have multiple sheets with the same name). `Error Handling` will help you here
4. This does not place any data on your worksheet. The amount of questions in regaurds to Copy/Paste on this site is **beyond plentiful**. `Offset` from your `Target` cell may help here. Also, you can loop through the selected column (`Target.Column`) and move to your new sheet if the cell has `x`
5. This can be be amended to check the `Target` cells format if you really want this to only fire when a 'green' cell is clicked

Comment: Thanks this is what i wanted, a framework for the best way to build this.

Answer (score -1):

So first thing first, maybe I didn't get the question right.

Just to clarify the question. Do you want to have some kind of Table of Contents on the First Sheet?

To do this, you need to have an Event Handler for this certain sheet or specifically for this certain ranges. You can either choose Worksheet_SelectionChange or Worksheet_Change Event depending on your desired result.

As for the Routine to create new Sheet and renaming it. You can use this reference

[Creating and Naming Worksheet in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840628/creating-and-naming-worksheet-in-excel-vba)

Comment: in the image i provided what is on the first sheet and what the newly created sheet should look like.

Comment: Why for the down vote? I provided where you can start and this is what i get? Very nice.

Comment: I DID NOT DOWN VOTE Anything, you realize other people have that ability...